# Bootstrap modal not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently moving my modal content from the index page to another page and linking them. This is working fine in all browsers except Safari.

For instance, if I change:

```
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#preferencesModal">Preferences</a>
```

to

```
<a href="preferences.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#preferencesModal">Preferences</a>
```

it does not load the modal in safari. It works fine in other browsers.